# Dynamically changing the title of a submenu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown, submenu

I want to create a dropdown menu of categories. When the page first loads I want the dropdown to say "Categories". I want to be able to click on a category like "Tops". Then the title of the dropdown changes to "Tops" not categories. Not really sure how to start this, I'm pretty new at coding. Found some code on W3 to use as my baseline.

```
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do that without having to use JavaScript just html and CSS for the creation of the dropdown and use JavaScript to handle the name changing event

One important thing to note is that when setting the new name with

```
title.innerHTML = name ;
```

It destroys the  original list and overrides it so after that statement we have to add the list back with

```
title.appendChild(list)
```

Here is the working code...

```js
var title = document.getElementById('title');
var list = document.getElementById('list');

let c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
let c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
let c3 = document.getElementById('c3');

var namec1 = c1.innerHTML; 
var namec2 = c2.innerHTML; 
var namec3 = c3.innerHTML; 

//console.log(name)
c1.addEventListener("click", function(e){

renameTitle(namec1)
// Add more event stuff here

});


c2.addEventListener("click", function(e){
renameTitle(namec2)
// Add more event stuff here

});


c3.addEventListener("click", function(e){
renameTitle(namec3)
// Add more event stuff here

});

function renameTitle(name)
{
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  title.innerHTML = name ;
  title.appendChild(list)
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  background: darkorange;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    color: #fff;
  background: darkorange;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
  
li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover,
li:focus-within {
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}

ul li ul {
    background: orange;
    visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
    left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li:focus-within > ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block
}

ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
  <li id='title'> Categories
      <ul class="dropdown" id='list'>
        <li id='c1'>Sub-1</li>
        <li id='c2'>Sub-2</li>
        <li id='c3'>Sub-3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    

      
  </ul>
</nav>
```

An and part of your comments to create a catogories element and add it to the list add

```js
var newItem = document.createElement('li');
newItem .innerHTML = 'catogories';

var list = document.getElementById("list");    // Get the <ul> element to insert a new node
list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);  // Insert <li> before the first child of <ul>
```

```html
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul>
      <li id='title'> Categories
          <ul class="dropdown" id='list'>
            <li id='c1'>Sub-1</li>
            <li id='c2'>Sub-2</li>
            <li id='c3'>Sub-3</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        

          
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! this is so helpful. Is there a way to keep Categories title in the dropdown menu? For example, you clicked "sub-3", title is now "sub-3" but when you click on the dropdown again it will display the title categories on the top the list?

Comment: yes you can added a snippet to the end of my original answer to show you how you just have to add the logic to the original function